# how to merge to different excel files into one new excel file using python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

the problem is i cant merge them all

first of all,at period one  i ask user to give the two paths of their excel files, as ExceloathH and ExcelpathL. so these the must be added to the new excle file
and then in period2 , the 2 excel paths should add to new excel file(at the new file , its a container of 4 excel files)
i want to merge these to file into one new excel file called : sys_excel

```
new_excel_by_user=str(input("write the name of your new EXCEL file:"))
user_excel = pd.ExcelWriter(new_excel_by_user+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
sys_excel=pd.ExcelWriter('sys_excel11.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

excel_list_H= []
excel_list_L=[]

for i in range(v):
   print("\npriod %d :"%(i+1))

   excelpathH=''+input(''+r"Insert your Excel path(HIGH):")
   excelpathL=''+input(''+r"Insert your Excel path(LOW):")
   excelpathH=excelpathH.replace('"', '')
   excelpathL=excelpathL.replace('"', '')
   dfH=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathH), engine='openpyxl' )
   dfL=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathL), engine='openpyxl' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly merge the DataFrames read from the Excel files without storing them in a list.
**Here's your updated version of code**

```
import pandas as pd
import os

new_excel_by_user = str(input("Write the name of your new EXCEL file: "))

sys_excel = pd.ExcelWriter('sys_excel11.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

merged_df_H = pd.DataFrame()
merged_df_L = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(v):
    print("\nPeriod %d :" % (i+1))

    excelpathH = input("Insert your Excel path (HIGH): ")
    excelpathL = input("Insert your Excel path (LOW): ")

    excelpathH = excelpathH.replace('"', '')
    excelpathL = excelpathL.replace('"', '')

    dfH = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathH), engine='openpyxl')
    dfL = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathL), engine='openpyxl')

    merged_df_H = pd.concat([merged_df_H, dfH])
    merged_df_L = pd.concat([merged_df_L, dfL])

# Write merged dataframes to a new Excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter(new_excel_by_user + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as user_excel:
    merged_df_H.to_excel(user_excel, sheet_name='High', index=False)
    merged_df_L.to_excel(user_excel, sheet_name='Low', index=False)

# Optionally, if you want to merge the data into 'sys_excel11.xlsx'
merged_df_H.to_excel(sys_excel, sheet_name='High', index=False)
merged_df_L.to_excel(sys_excel, sheet_name='Low', index=False)

sys_excel.save()
```

Here I just directly merges the Excel files into the `merged_df_H` and `merged_df_L` Data-frames without using intermediate lists.

Comment: THANKS ALOT, BUT THERE IS PROBLEM. it write down all excel file below each other, i measn that excel2 goes under all of the element in excel1

Comment: and also , i dont want multiple sheets, i want them all in one sheet called "Sheet1" , and one after the other in columns

Comment: Fix this yourself. If not how will you learn.

Comment: i tried using .transpose() but it did not work

Comment: i fixed it.....

Comment: you are genius.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
data_file='filepath'
df=[]
for file in os.listdir(data_file):
  if file.endswith('.csv'):
   df.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_file,file)))
m_df=pd.concat(df,ignore_index=True)

m_df.to_excel("name.xlsx")
```

Comment: i dont want them to be list, iwant them as dataframe

Comment: it is a dataframe @soura elle